# Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 via Wubi, no sound. Any help?

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, mute

As the title says, I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop using wubi, and I have no sound. `$ pavucontrol` shows sound playing, but nothing is coming out through speakers *or* headphones. You can access my [sound information](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6ac31857775f78099d60dc7a51b2524fb28e23da) there.

Sound has worked previously with Kubuntu install on the same machine, and works fine in Windows 7. Please help!

Comment: run `alsamixer` and see whether the master volume is low

Comment: @Web-E I've checked `alsamixer` and everything is turned up and not muted.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the OS again.
Had same problem once. Tried many solutions, like
reinstalling alsa, changing the Alsa configuration file etc., restarting audio management service. But none worked.
I just reinstalled the OS and it started working. so try it. Thank you.